# How to calculate algorithm time complex

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I am trying to multiple two big integer with [`Karatsuba`](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/divide-and-conquer-set-2-karatsuba-algorithm-for-fast-multiplication/) algorithm.
I known that `O(n)` is time complexity and `T(n)` is worst-case time complexity.

Can some one please explain why:

```
T(n) = 4T(n/2) + O(n) is O(n^2)
```

And

```
T(n) = 3T(n/2) + O(n) is O(n^1.59)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
T(n) = 4T(n/2) + O(n)
```

According to the Master theorem:

```
T(n) is O(n^log_2(4)) = O(n^2)
```

and

```
T(n) = 3T(n/2) + O(n)
```

is

```
T(n) = O(log_2(3)) ~ O(n^1,5849)
```

so you can round it to `1.590`.

Comment: Thanks. Its generic form case 1 of Master theorem.

Comment: @NhatDinh yes it is